# What does CALayer know that I do not when zooming

Tags: objective-c, uiview, calayer, zooming

How can I draw as smoothly as CALayer does while zooming?

As seen in the third (tallest) image the white border is drawn with accurate, `anti-aliased` rendering.

However neither my labels (even though I set the `contentScaleFactor`) nor my hand drawn circles (even though I turn `anti aliasing` on) are.

How can I have anti-aliased rendering for either UIKit components or hand-drawn graphics that scale with the zooming factor as smoothly as what CALayer does?

What's the magic?

[image: small]
[image: medium]
[image: large]

The white border is drawn using the view's CALayer:

```
    self.layer.cornerRadius = frame.size.width / 2.0f ;
    self.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor ;
    self.layer.borderWidth = 3.0f ;
```

The numbers are UILabel's

```
    CGFloat contentScale = self.zoomScale * [UIScreen mainScreen].scale; // Handle retina
    label.contentScaleFactor = contentScale;
```

And given:

```
    typedef struct {
        CGRect      rect ;
        CGColorRef  color ;
    } EventColor ;
```

the 4 circles are drawn using CoreGraphics

```
    ::CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing(context, true) ;
    ::CGContextSetShouldAntialias(context, true) ;
    // ...
    EventColor ec = ...
    // ...
    ::CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, ec.color) ;
    ::CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, ec.rect) ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I misunderstood what `contentScaleFactor` was meant for, and discovered that what I really was after was CALayer's `contentScale`.

The upshot is that the `drawRect` method in whatever UIView subclass can go ahead and pretend that the zooming scale is always set to 1.0 provided that the view's layer's contentScale is set to reflect the current zoom level of the scroll view.

```
- (void) scrollViewDidEndZooming: (UIScrollView *) scrollView
                        withView: (UIView *) view
                         atScale: (float) scale {

    scale *= [UIScreen mainScreen].scale ;
    for (UIView * v in view.subviews) {
        v.layer.contentsScale = scale ;
        [v setNeedsDisplay] ;
    }
}
```

The example above assumes that the scroll view contains a non opaque container view which in turn contains every actual views whose `layer.contentScale` needs adjusting.

Comment: Is it contentScale or contentsScale ? Note the extra 's' in the second one